# Error in R while compiling the markdown

Tags: r

I am trying to save a xgboost code in Rmarkdown to knit HTML document. I am getting an error.
The code is completely executable in "R".

### Fatal error: creation of tmpfile failed -- set TMPDIR suitably?

The error is same when I try to run knit Pdf/word.

Someone please help me.

Thank you

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the code that generates the error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the temporary directory cannot be created. Trying making your own temporary directory or setting it to the working directory:

```
Sys.setenv(TMPDIR = ".")
```